# Unbind mouseout event in jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, css

**Hi!**

I got the following code :

```
function UpdatePriceSubscribeButton() {

    if (_userPriceSubscribe > 0) {
        $("#btUpdatePriceSubscribing").removeClass("con");
        $("#btUpdatePriceSubscribing").addClass("conActive");
        $("#btUpdatePriceSubscribing").unbind('onmouseover').unbind('onmouseout');
    }
    else {
        $("#btUpdatePriceSubscribing").removeClass("conActive");
        $("#btUpdatePriceSubscribing").addClass("con");
        $("#btUpdatePriceSubscribing").mouseover(function() { this.className = 'conActive'});
        $("#btUpdatePriceSubscribing").mouseout(function() {this.className = 'con'});
    }
};
```

The problem with this is that when onmouseout the class will be changed even if the _userPriceSubscribe was set to 1?

What Im trying to do here is to change the current class and the hover class on client side with jquery.

**Edit1:** I have also troed $("#btUpdatePriceSubscribing").unbind('omouseenter mouseleave'); that is sugested here : http://api.jquery.com/hover/

**Edit2:** This works :

```
function UpdatePriceSubscribeButton() {

    if (_userPriceSubscribe > 0) {
        $("#btUpdatePriceSubscribing").removeClass("con");
        $("#btUpdatePriceSubscribing").addClass("conActive");
        $("#btUpdatePriceSubscribing").unbind('omouseenter mouseleave');
    }
    else {
        $("#btUpdatePriceSubscribing").removeClass("conActive");
        $("#btUpdatePriceSubscribing").addClass("con");

        $("#btUpdatePriceSubscribing").hover(function () { this.className = 'conActive' }, function () { this.className = 'con' });
    }
};
```

But is this a good way of doing it?

**BestRegards**

Comment: How is `UpdatePriceSubscribeButton` called?

Comment: It is called on pageload and when a Ajax call is done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solved my problem :

```
function UpdatePriceSubscribeButton() {

    if (_userPriceSubscribe > 0) {
        $("#btUpdatePriceSubscribing").removeClass("con");
        $("#btUpdatePriceSubscribing").addClass("conActive");
        $("#btUpdatePriceSubscribing").unbind('omouseenter mouseleave');
    }
    else {
        $("#btUpdatePriceSubscribing").removeClass("conActive");
        $("#btUpdatePriceSubscribing").addClass("con");

        $("#btUpdatePriceSubscribing").hover(function () { this.className = 'conActive' }, function () { this.className = 'con' });
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Would it make sense to set up *one* onmouseout / onmouseover handler that looks for the  price inside the mouseout handler ?

```
$("#btUpdatePriceSubscribing").mouseover(function () {
   if (_userPriceSubscribe > 0) {
       this.className = "..."
   }
}
```

(Otherwise I'm not sure I get what you're trying to do...)

Answer (score 1):

The event name is `mouseenter` not `omouseenter`. So, unless `omouseenter` is a custom event, you'll want to change this line:

`$("#btUpdatePriceSubscribing").unbind('omouseenter mouseleave');`

to:

`$("#btUpdatePriceSubscribing").unbind('mouseenter mouseleave');`